# Android AndEngine change text dynamically

Tags: android, andengine

I am using custom font in andengine and when the user click that ui I need to change the color of my ui.Here is my code.

```
Text exit=new Text(250, 390, this.mPlokFont, "Exit");
exit.setColor(255,0, 0, 255);  
scene.attachChild(exit);
```

but it doesn't work. My font :

```
mPlokFont = FontFactory.createFromAsset(this.mPlokFontTexture, this, "Plok.ttf", 16, true, Color.WHITE);
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use ChangeableText instead of Text

Answer (score 4):

I'm pretty sure you are facing this issue because you are using premultiplied alpha in the font texture.  Try this

```
mFontTexture = new BitmapTextureAtlas(256, 256, TextureOptions.BILINEAR);
mUIFont = new Font(m_FontTexture, Typeface.create(Typeface.DEFAULT, Typeface.BOLD), 32, true, Color.WHITE);
```

and it should work.  AFAIK, premultiplied alpha means the RGB values in the texture are already multiplied by an alpha value, so calling .setAlpha() will not change anything (it will not be applied.

Comment: Well I already fixed my problem but here +1 for the trouble of posting an answer ;)